# Install4j - Is there any build-in way keeping certain files after rollback?

Tags: java, install4j

When the installer fails and starting in rollback process it tries to delete all installation files.
Is there any build-in way configuring the rollback process to keep certain files like LOGS files for further investigation?

Answer (score 0):

To diagnose a failure, start the installer with

```
-Dinstall4j.alternativeLogfile=<writable path to log file>
```

then the log file will be written to the specified path and is not deleted by the rollback.

To copy other files so that they are not deleted by a rollback, you can copy them in case of a rollback with the "Optional Rollback Script" property of a "Run script" action. In that script, use  `Files.copy`:

```
import java.nio.file.*;
Files.copy(Paths.get("source path"), Paths.get("target path"));
```

Comment: Thanks. Can I also specify other files to be written or not to be deleted by the rollback?